# Get id from URL using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, video, iframe

I want to get the video id from below URL using JavaScript and then insert it into an iframe:

Sample URL:

```
http://test.com/dd.php?video=123
```

Sample iframe:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" width="640" height="432" 
src="https://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/insert id here></iframe>
```

I want to add the video id at the end of dailymotion URL in the iframe.
The src in the iframe should look like this:

```
src="https://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/123
```

In PHP it would be done like this, but I need to solve it in JavaScript:

```
<?php echo $_Get["video"]; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScript you can get it from `URLSearchParams`:

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const videoId = urlParams.get('video');
```

Answer (score 0):

Get prams from current url:

```
const videoId = new URL('http://test.com/dd.php?video=123').searchParams.get('video');
```

Then insert it into iframe tag

```
const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');

// split url by "/" to have array of url parts
const url = iframe.getAttribute('src').split('/');

// update last element to new id
url[url.length - 1] = videoId;

// set new url to iframe src attribute
iframe.setAttribute('src', url.join('/'));
```